# How to read gene regulatory network edge list files?

Tags: gene, networks, transcriptome-regulation

The following is an excerpt from an edge list file from the Gene Regulatory Database, [YeastNet v3](https://www.inetbio.org/yeastnet/)

```
YML100W YMR261C 5.73968189451551
YDR074W YML100W 5.73143623470086
YDR074W YMR261C 5.72385204041689
YML106W YMR271C 5.64698433340441
YGR240C YMR205C 5.64063955646679
YDL131W YDL182W 5.63907349642605
YNL037C YOR136W 5.62782704009976
YHR208W YJR148W 5.61712512462848
YAL062W YOR375C 5.59956647235823
YNL104C YOR108W 5.59046546303091
YGR132C YGR231C 5.58996626839351
YBR140C YOL081W 5.58738025271142
YDR453C YML028W 5.58281825879471
YNL096C YOR096W 5.58060076040965
YGR180C YJL026W 5.57785446902287
YGR056W YLR357W 5.57582611528462
YBR009C YNL030W 5.57261292043205
YMR169C YMR170C 5.55866364259678
YAR071W YBR093C 5.55668852247789
YER081W YIL074C 5.55252000887001
```

What do these rows mean?

Comment: It also depends which file you have downloaded. Apparently the evidence can be based on various inputs such as co-citation in PubMed, or co-occurrence of domains... The details are listed on their webpage.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about it on the [website](https://www.inetbio.org/yeastnet/), the last column is the Log likelihood scores (LLS) between the genes in the first two columns. An LLS of 0 means not better than random link.

On the website they show papers with fuller details about the statistics.